# Node Async/Await/Promise.All not waiting for other to complete

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

I have 3 functions which I need to run in order and one needs to finish before the other runs so I've done this:

```
var fs = require('fs');

async function create() {

    fs.writeFile('newfile.txt', 'some text here', (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('File is created successfully.');
        return ('File is created successfully.');
    }); 

}

async function waitt() {
    setTimeout(() => { return 'waited!' }, 10000);
}

async function read() {

    fs.readFile('newfile.txt', {encoding: 'utf-8'}, (err,data) => {
        if (!err) {
            console.log('received data: ' + data);
            return ('received data: ' + data);
        } else {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });

}

async function process() {

    let [r1, r2, r3] = await Promise.all([create(), waitt(), read()]);

    console.log(r1 + ' ' + r2 + ' ' + r3);

}


process();
```

So, process() runs create() which creates a file, then run waitt() which just pauses and finally read() shows the contents of the file.

The issue I'm having is that it's running in this order:

```
create()
read()
and then waitt()
```

instead of

```
create()
waitt()
read()
```

which is what I want.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Create and read aren't actually promisified. Returns from callbacks don't actually return from the outer function.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - `waitt` is also badly written

Comment: @Nik Kyriakides already provided a good answer, if you're working with `fs` in conjunction with promises, I'd also recommend using this package [fs-extra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra), it adds functionality where a lot of functions return promises by themselves if you do not provide a callback

Comment: Furthermore, `Promise.all()` means the functions run in parallel but you seem to want them to run sequentially

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to make them run one at the time

Comment: it's actually running create then waitt then read = it's the asynchronous code inside those functions that runs in a non-determined order ... because asynchrony  ... even if your code correctly  returned a Promise that resolved at the correct time, you still wouldn't have the order you are looking for ... you want a promise chain, or await each function in turn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't work:

```
async function waitt() {
  setTimeout(() => { return 'waited!' }, 10000);
}
```

Because, you're `return`-ing from within the `setTimeout` callback, not the `async`-marked `wait` function.

To mix callback-style code and async/await you must first convert callback style code to use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), or use [fs-extra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra) which already provides `fs` functions returning promises.

Something like this:

```
function waitt() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('waited...')
    }, 10000)
  })
}
```

The same applies to the rest of your functions.

Also note that if a function explicitly returns a Promise, it doesn't need to be marked as `async` to be awaited, since await essentially works with Promises.

Now for the order:

[Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) doesn't guarantee order, for that you might be able to get away with a simple [for..of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), or just call the functions yourself.

```js
function wait() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('waited...')
      resolve('foo')
    }, 500)
  })
}

// Assume this is your promisified read function.
function read() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('read...')
      resolve('bar')
    }, 500)
  })
}

// Assume this is your promisified create function.
function create() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('created...')
      resolve('baz')
    }, 500)
  })
}

;(async () => {
  try {
    await create()
    await wait()
    await read()
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
})()
```

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that Promise.all does not guarantee the order of processing, just that all the promises in the list are processed.

Can you not just say:

```
await create();
await read();
await waitt();
```

Comment: so you think those three functions are written correctly, and they return a Promise that resolves once the asynchronous task is finished?